# How to solve a word problem when given width and height of the following?

Tags: arithmetic, quadratics, word-problem

The width of a room is $4$ feet shorter than its length, and its height is $3$ feet less than its length. The area of $4$ walls is larger than the sum of the areas of the floor and ceiling by $134$ square feet. What is the length of the room?
This is what i got from the question 
[image]

I don't get about the area thing? how would I solve this problem?

Comment: $(w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4)- (c+f) = 134\text{ ft}^2$, where $w_i$ is the area of the wall $i$ and $c$ and $f$ are the area of the ceiling and floor respectively.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have drawn the diagram correctly. The width is marked on a side that is actually the height of the room.

Answer (score 1):

So you know that the Area of the Ceiling and Floor together is $$A_{f,c} = 2L(L-4)$$
you also know that the sum of the other four walls is $$A_w = 2L(L-3) + 2(L-4)(L-3)$$ and by the constraint you laid out we have that $$A_w-A_{f,c}=134$$ so then we have to solve the quadratic $$2L(L-3)+2(L-4)(L-3)-2L(L-4)-134=0$$
which can be simplified down to $$2L^2-6L +2(L^2-7L+12)-2L^2+8L-134=2L^2-12L-110=0$$
so you just need to solve $$L^2-6L-55=0$$ and that factors to $$(L-11)(L+5)=0$$ and you get that $$L=11$$ because length can't be negative.

Comment: i don't understand how you got the area of floor and ceiling, shouldn't you multiply the area of floor * the area of ceiling

Comment: Area of a rectangle is equal to the length times the width. The area of the ceiling and floor is the same, so to have the area of both you just multiply by 2.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence of the problem translates mathematically to
\begin{align*}
w &= l-4 & h&=l-3\tag{1}
\end{align*}
The second sentence translates to
$$
2\,lh+2\,wh=134+2\,lw\tag{2}
$$
Dividing equation $(2)$ through by $2$ gives
$$
\frac{2\,lh+2\,wh}{2}=\frac{134+2\,lw}{2} \implies lh+wh=67+lw\tag{3}
$$
Substituting the relations in $(1)$ into equation $(3)$ gives
$$
l(l-3)+(l-4)(l-3)=67+l(l-4)\tag{4}
$$
Simplifying $(4)$ gives
$$
l^2-6\,l-55=0\tag{5}
$$
Can you solve equation $(5)$ for $l$?

Comment: I don't get it how did you find the area of the 4 walls or anything about the second sentence? how did you do it?

Comment: Why would you multiply lenght and height?

Comment: Could you explain the second sentence?